# Fuzzy lookup algorithm issues

Tags: algorithm, vba, excel, fuzzy-search

I'm using Alan (al_b_cnu)'s Fuzzy lookups comparing two sets of names. I have some queries about how the algorithms can be altered however as I'm not getting the results I expected having previously used fuzzyvlookups for a similar task.

The two columns have the following name structures:

Column A: < Title > < First Name > < Surname >

Column B: < Surname > < First Initial > < Second initial >

I've tried all three of Alan's algorithms explained here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/195635-fuzzy-matching-new-version-plus-explanation.html

However, my results have been poor or non-existent to say the least.

What do you recommend for altering the algorithms so that there is more likely to be effective matching?

Comment: Maybe you could include the code that you've written, even though the results were disappointing. That way we would have a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish. Also -- *how* are the results different from expectations? Some actual data to run your code on would be helpful, together with a description of intended vs. actual results.

Comment: Examples of your input / output, what you find unacceptable, and what your expected output is would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have an SQL server available? https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/fuzzy-searches-sql-server/?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=pubemail&utm_content=20170307-slota2&utm_term=simpletalkmain AND https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/string-comparisons-sql-metaphone-algorithm/ could be of help then.